# Why local variable doesn't save value?

Tags: mysql, mysql5

I'm writing query in mysql5.7 to emulate dense_rank(). I have problem with scope of variable.

I've tried using variable in diffrent ways, but always Place in rank is wrong counted. It seems that variable `@total` i wrong  set.

```
SET @row_number = 1;
SET @total =null;

SELECT
    CONCAT(`u`.`name`, ' ' ,`u`.`surname`) as `User`,
    SUM(`oi`.quantity * `oi`.price)  as `Total amount`,
    CASE
        WHEN @total = SUM(`oi`.quantity * `oi`.price) THEN
            @row_number
        ELSE
            @row_number:= @row_number + 1
        END
    as `Place in rank`,
    @total := SUM(`oi`.quantity * `oi`.price)
FROM `user` u
    LEFT JOIN `order` o ON `u`.`user_id`=`o`.user_id
    LEFT JOIN `order_item` oi ON `oi`.`order_id`=`o`.order_id
WHERE `o`.`date` > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
GROUP BY user
ORDER BY `Total amount` DESC
```

Here's my fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5yiyp6Zyt2eB5h26RT5Lmf/10

Column `place in rank` has actual values 4,3,2 but I

expect 1,1,2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case SELECT is evaluated before ORDER BY, because no index can be used for the the ORDER BY clause. And the columns could be evaluated in any order (especially when aggregate functions are involved). SQL is not a procedural language. You can though try to "force" the execution/evaluation order. In this case you need (at least) to wrap your query into an ordered subquery. Also - The `@row_number` should be initialized as `0`:

```
SET @row_number = 0;
SET @total = null;

SELECT *,
  CASE WHEN @total = `Total amount`
    THEN @row_number
    ELSE @row_number:= @row_number + 1
  END AS `Place in rank`,
  @total := `Total amount`
FROM (
  SELECT
    CONCAT(`u`.`name`, ' ' ,`u`.`surname`) as `User`,
    SUM(`oi`.quantity * `oi`.price)  as `Total amount`
  FROM `user` u
  LEFT JOIN `order` o ON `u`.`user_id`=`o`.user_id
  LEFT JOIN `order_item` oi ON `oi`.`order_id`=`o`.order_id
  WHERE `o`.`date` > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
  GROUP BY user
  ORDER BY `Total amount` DESC
) x
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6QswvMFLTW81NibYvhhcii/0)

This might work now. But you never know, when it doesn't. Consider to solve such tasks in a procedural language, or upgrade to a version with window functions.

However - If forced to use "SQL", I would write the query a bit differently:

```
SELECT x.*,
  CASE WHEN @total = `Total amount`
    THEN @row_number
    ELSE @row_number:= @row_number + 1 + 0*(@total := `Total amount`)
  END AS `Place in rank`
FROM (
  SELECT
    CONCAT(`u`.`name`, ' ' ,`u`.`surname`) as `User`,
    SUM(`oi`.quantity * `oi`.price)  as `Total amount`
  FROM `user` u
  LEFT JOIN `order` o ON `u`.`user_id`=`o`.user_id
  LEFT JOIN `order_item` oi ON `oi`.`order_id`=`o`.order_id
  WHERE `o`.`date` > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
  GROUP BY user
  ORDER BY `Total amount` DESC
) x
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row_number := 0, @total := null) init_vars
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6YbCTf4sDyUrDdeMy3K1tR/0)

Comment: Note that `WHERE o.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)` will convert the first JOIN to an INNER JOIN. I don't know if you want that. And since it's not part of the problem, I didn't mention it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need control over the order rows are evaluated. This can be accomplished by using a subquery to generate the totals first. Then calculate the rank using the subquery.

```
set @last_total = null;
set @rank = 0;

select *,
    CASE
        WHEN `total amount` = @last_total THEN
            @rank
        ELSE
            @rank := @rank + 1
        END
    as `Place in rank`,
    @last_total := `total amount`
from (
    SELECT
        CONCAT(`u`.`name`, ' ' ,`u`.`surname`) as `User`,
        SUM(`oi`.quantity * `oi`.price)  as `Total amount`
    FROM `user` u
        LEFT JOIN `order` o ON `u`.`user_id`=`o`.user_id
        LEFT JOIN `order_item` oi ON `oi`.`order_id`=`o`.order_id
    WHERE `o`.`date` > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
    GROUP BY `user`
) user_totals
order by `total amount` desc;
```

If you can use MySQL 8, it features [`dense_rank`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_dense-rank) which does all this for you.

```
with user_totals as (
    SELECT
        CONCAT(`u`.`name`, ' ' ,`u`.`surname`) as `User`,
        SUM(`oi`.quantity * `oi`.price)  as `Total amount`
    FROM `user` u
        LEFT JOIN `order` o ON `u`.`user_id`=`o`.user_id
        LEFT JOIN `order_item` oi ON `oi`.`order_id`=`o`.order_id
    WHERE `o`.`date` > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
    GROUP BY `User`
)
select *,
  dense_rank() over( order by `Total amount` desc )
from user_totals;
```

Here I've split the query up with a [Common Table Expression](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cte/) to calculate the totals which makes `dense_rank()` not have to repeat that calculation.